# Dragover issue in Meteor

Tags: drag-and-drop, meteor

I've just started learning Meteor (and Templating). I really enjoy it so far. However, I'm running into a weird issue using HTML5 native drag n drop events on a table. Note that I'm **not** using jQuery events.

I have a table with droppable `td` and draggable `elements`.

So my `table` template looks like this:

```html
<template name="table">
<table>
  {{#each row}}
     <tr>
        {{#each col}}
           <td>
             {{#each elements}}
               {{>element}}
             {{/each}}
            </td>
        {{/each}}
     </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
</template>
```

```js
Template.tasktable.events({
  'dragover td': function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  },
  'drop td': function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = evt.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    Collection.update({_id: id}, {$set: {value: this.value}});
  }
});
```

Then my `element` template looks like this:

```html
<template name="element">
  <div draggable="true">{{value}}</div>
</template>
```

```js
Template.element.events({
  'dragstart': function(evt, tmpl) {
     evt.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this._id);
  }
});
```

For some reason that is melting my brain, the `drag over` event is being followed by a **rendering** event, as you can see on the dev tool image here: http://cl.ly/image/3O1S2d1j1f1a

This is extremely painful as `dragover` is being fired a **lot** and subsequently the `drop`event is queued after several seconds. I have no idea where that comes from, it looks like **domutils.js** is being called.

Hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks so much.

### EDIT

I managed to prevent the rendering event to appear, by removing the `dragover` event from the `Template events` and adding

`$(document).on('dragover', 'td', function(evt) {evt.preventDefault();})`

which is jQuery but doesn't get caught by domutils.js or listeners.js from Meteor.

Comment: Try running meteor with `mrt --release template-engine-preview-10.1`

Comment: Hi @Cuberto, thanks a lot, it does improve things (although breaking some packages apparently). It looks like drag events are now jQuery events (so I needed to use `evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text')`).

Comment: It won't work with anything that uses [`{{#constant}}`, `{{#isolate}}` , or `preserve`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview#wiki-no-more-constant-isolate-or-preserve), because they're now unnecessary. Also, here's a note about the [events using jQuery](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview#wiki-events-use-jquery). The new templating engine is supposed to be merged into the Meteor core by 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Cuberto answer in the comments, I've successfully managed to solve the problem by upgrading Meteor with their new upcoming templating engine Blaze UI (which is still work in progress and not released yet).

Blaze UI uses jQuery events, and this seems to fix restyling layout issues mentioned above.

Should you want to permanently upgrade to Blaze UI, you need to run from the terminal:

```
meteor update --release template-engine-preview-10.1
```

Should you want to keep using the old templating engine that comes with the current release of Meteor (0.7.0.1), the fix I mentioned in the EDIT of my original post solves it:

```
$(document).on('dragover', 'td', function(evt) {evt.preventDefault();})
```